# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$ converges uniformly on $R$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I need help with this problem:

> Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$$ converges uniformly on $R$.

So, I tried using the Weierstrass $M$-test. This is what I did:

$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$ so by the $M$-test $|f_n(x)|\leq M_n$, so $\left|\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}\right|\leq \left|\frac{x}{n(nx^2)}\right|=\left|\frac{x}{n^2x^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$, and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so the series converges uniformly on $R$.

Is what I'm doing right? Because the assistant teacher said that we can't use the $M$-test here, why? If I'm wrong, how can I solve this correctly?

Comment: Note $x/x^2 = 1/x$ not $1$. You need to consider $|x|<1$ and $|x|\ge 1$.

Comment: But wouln't $\left|\frac{x}{n^2x^2}\right| =  \frac{1}{n^2x}$ still be less than $\frac{1}{n^2}? since the denominator is bigger?

Answer (score 8):

Note that $1 + nx^2 \geqslant 2\sqrt{n}|x|$ since $(1 - \sqrt{n}|x|)^2 \geqslant 0 $ and

$$ \left|\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}\right| = \frac{|x|}{n(1+nx^2)}\leqslant \frac{|x|}{n}\frac{1}{2|x|\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$$

By the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) the series is uniformly convergent for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ since $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} n^{-3/2}$ is a convergent p-series.

Comment: I didn't understand the $\frac{|x|}{n(1+nx^2)}\leqslant \frac{|x|}{n}\frac{1}{2|x|\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$ part, can you explain it more please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. I find this topic about convergence pretty hard.

Comment: We just showed that the series is uniformly convergent for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by the Weierstrass M-test since $|f_n(x)| \leqslant 1/(2n^{3/2})$ for ALL $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (including $0$ where $f_n(0) = 0$). The series $\sum n^{-3/2}$ is a convergent p-series.  What are you having trouble with?  Do you know the statement of the M-test?

Comment: The bound that you found $1/(n^2|x|)$ won't help since it still depends on $x$ and becomes unbounded near $x = 0$.  That does not mean we can't find a better bound.

Comment: You could use it to prove uniform convergence for $x \geqslant a > 0$ say since then we have $|f_n(x)| < 1/(n^2a)$ and the series $\sum n^{-2}$ converges.

Comment: I'm having trouble with how you came with that bound, with $\frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}. I understand everything else and why it converges with taht bound. But I don't understand the reasoning behind founding it.

Comment: You made a good attempt and found a bound (that works for proving uniform convergence away from $0$) but it is not "tight' enough near $0$.  Looking at $1 + nx^2$ from past experience completing squares I know that $1 + nx^2 - 2\sqrt{n}|x| = (1 - \sqrt{n}|x|)^2$ and as a square this is always greater than or equal to $0$.  I put $|x|$ here and not $x$ because I know it is what I want to cancel in the numerator.  Since $1 + nx^2 - 2\sqrt{n}|x| \geqslant 0$, it follows that $1+nx^2 \geqslant 2 \sqrt{n}|x|$ which implies $\frac{1}{1+nx^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}|x|}$.

Comment: I get it, that's pretty clever. Thanks.

Comment: One question, would it work to take the derivative and find the maximum point?

Comment: Yes -- the maximum is at $x^* = 1/\sqrt{n}$ where $f_n(x^*) = 1/(2\sqrt{n})$.  So now you found another trick yourself!

Comment: $x^*=1/\sqrt{n}$ is found by taking the derivative of $\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$, right?

Comment: Yes -- I left out the extra $n$ so it should be $f_n(x^*) = 1/(2n\sqrt{n})$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_n(x)$ be the $n$th summand. A little calculus shows the maximum value of $f_n$ over $[0,\infty)$ occurs at $x= 1/\sqrt {n},$ giving a value of $\dfrac{1}{2n^{3/2}}.$ Because $f_n$ is odd, we have $\sup_{\mathbb R}|f_n|\le  \dfrac{1}{2n^{3/2}}.$ By Weierstrass M, the series converges uniformly on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: By taking the first derivative, I found that the maximum was $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, not $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are right, and that makes it simpler. Thanks for the correction, now edited.

Comment: Ok, thanks! To test if it a maximum or minimum I have to use the second derivative, but isn't there any other way? Because it is too tedious.

Comment: The derivative is $f_n'(x)=(n-n^2x^2)/[(n(1+nx^2)]^2.$ This is positive to the left of $1/\sqrt n,$ negative to the right of $1/\sqrt n.$

Comment: What do you mean with positive to the left and negative to the right?

Comment: $f_n'>0,x\in [0,1/\sqrt n),$ $f_n'<0,x\in [1/\sqrt n,\infty).$